# WebGL - Hardware skinning with a bone texture

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am trying to get hardware skinning with WebGL, and can't seem to get it to work with a texture containing all my matrices.
I am feeding a float texture like this:

```
var buffer = new Float32Array(...);
... 
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, buffer.byteLength / 16, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, buffer);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

In addition to the texture, I also send the relative size of each matrix and vector compared to the total size of the texture - this is used to map bone indices to texture coordinates, since there is no texel fetch in WebGL.
E.g. if I have 40 bones, then each matrix is 1/40, and each vector is 1/40/4.

Here are the relevant vertex shader parts:

```
...
uniform sampler2D u_bone_map;
uniform float u_matrix_fraction;
uniform float u_vector_fraction;
...
mat4 boneMatrix(float bone) {
  return mat4(texture2D(u_bone_map, vec2(u_matrix_fraction * bone, 0)),
              texture2D(u_bone_map, vec2(u_matrix_fraction * bone + u_vector_fraction, 0)),
              texture2D(u_bone_map, vec2(u_matrix_fraction * bone + u_vector_fraction * 2.0, 0)),
              texture2D(u_bone_map, vec2(u_matrix_fraction * bone + u_vector_fraction * 3.0, 0)));
}
...
```

This doesn't work, and no matter how I try to change it, I just get junk on my screen.
Is this feasible without sane functions, like texelFetch (and actual uniform buffers)?

I have the same code running with a uniform array of matrices, but with my current setup it can't support more than 62 bones (because of the maximum uniform vectors restrictions), which is not enough for some 3D models.

Comment: What is a "bone texture"?

Comment: A texture object that stores all your bone matrices as "pixels", so you can access them in the vertex shader through normal texture access functions.
This works well with texelFetch or using a buffer texture, since they were meant to be used with arbitrary data, but it's less obvious how to take advantage of it with only normal 2D texture fetches.

A texture is better than a uniform array of matrices, because it is much faster to load, and has less size restrictions (I wrote about those issues above).

Comment: Why are you using a 2D texture while only using one single line of it? Wait, don't say WebGL doesn't even support 1D textures, meh. And are you sure the `glTexImage2D` call is successful at all (what does `glGetError` say)? I remember ES (and thus Web) to be more strict in its requirements for a matching internal and external format, thus you might want to either use a floating point internal format (`GL_RGBA32F`) or a byte external format (`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`).

Comment: ...In the end a fixed-point internal format for a texture that stores arbitrary rigid-body matrices is probably not the best idea in the first place.

Comment: @ChristianRau
Yeah WebGL removed support from any decent feature of OpenGL (or ES did, never used it).
The texture loads fine, WebGL reports errors on its own so there is no need to check manually.
I guess I'll just dump hardware skinning, WebGL is too ridiculous for this.

Comment: @user2503048 I wonder though what centipede it is you want to skin, since 62 bones should be quite enough for a human. Just dumping hardware skinning would not be good idea, since it's *the* schoolbook use-case for vertex shaders. It isn't so much that ES removed, it's not that different from desktop 2.0, it just doesn't have all the *newer* things that came *after* 2.0, like TBOs, UBOs and such. Still float textures should actually be supported (and be it at least by an extension).

Comment: Float textures are supported by an extension, but texelFetch (the only sane way to get arbitrary data from normal textures) isn't.
I am making a model viewer, so I don't control the amount of bones, however I have already seen 60.
I could do a bone count and decide on that whether to use hardware or software skinning, but like I said, using a uniform array seems to be slower than just doing all the transformation on the CPU.

Comment: Excuse me, it appears that I was stupid and didn't notice the matrix uniform uploading variant in WebGL is the fv one. Uploading all the matrices in one go is quite fast.
This still doesn't remove the number of uniforms restrictions, but at least it's an improvement.